# Find the roots of the quadratics function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A problem on Khan Academy that I can't seem to wrap my head around...

$$-3x^{ 2 }=x-6$$

This is how I manipulated the equation...

$$3x^{ 2 }+x-6=0$$

This is how Sal did...

$$-3x^{ 2 }-x+6=0$$

When applying the quadratic formula to both... the roots are different. Or at least they are when I try to solve it. I don't understand why my answer is wrong.

Comment: You must be making a mistake in your computation.

Comment: What is Khan Academy?

Comment: @HoracioOliveira: The Internet is your friend :-)

Comment: Sometimes it is ..... Evil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying the quadratic formula to $3x^2+x-6=0$:

$$x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4(3)(-6)}}{2\cdot3}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+72}}6=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{73}}6\;.$$

Applying it to $-3x^2-x+6=0$:

$$x=\frac{-(-1)\pm\sqrt{(-1)^2-4(-3)(6)}}{2(-3)}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{73}}{-6}=\frac{(-1)(-1\mp\sqrt{73}}{(-1)(6)}=\frac{-1\mp\sqrt{73}}6\;.$$

In both cases you get $\frac16(-1+\sqrt{73})$ and $\frac16(-1-\sqrt{73})$.

If the conversion of $1\pm\sqrt{73}$ to $(-1)(-1\mp\sqrt{73})$ is troublesome for you, remember that $1\pm\sqrt{73}$ is shorthand for the pair of numbers $1+\sqrt{73}$ and $1-\sqrt{73}$. If you factor $-1$ out of each of these, you get $(-1)(-1-\sqrt{73})$ and $(-1)(-1+\sqrt{73})$, respectively, which can be abbreviated to $(-1)(-1\mp\sqrt{73})$ if we want to keep the same order for the two numbers.

Comment: Glad to see you're back.

Comment: Welcome back, Brian! You've been missed.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Applying quadratic formula to first: $a = 3, b=1, c =-1, x = \dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4\times3\times-6}}{2\times3} = \dfrac{-1\pm \sqrt{73}}{6}$

Applying quadratic formula to second: $a = -3, b=-1, c =1, x = \dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{(-1)^2-4\times3\times-6}}{2\times-3} = \dfrac{1\pm \sqrt{73}}{-6} = \dfrac{-1\pm \sqrt{73}}{6}$